# If else nesting. How best to implement?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes an array of states.

```
Example:
State 1, [stage-is-empty, stage-is-green-done, stage-no-date];
State 2, [stage-is-done, stage-no-date, stage-is-yellow];
State 3, [stage-is-green, stage-is-red];
Etc.
```

It is necessary to return the worst element found.
"stage-no-date" is worst,
"stage-is-green-done" is better

My function:

```
const setTotalIndForStage = (arrayInd) => {
    let restul = {};
    arrayInd = arrayInd.filter((item, i) => arrayInd.indexOf(item) === i);
    restul.TOTAL_IND = 'stage-is-empty';
    restul.TOTAL_TEXT = '';

    if (arrayInd.length > 0) {
        restul.TOTAL_IND = arrayInd.findIndex(e => e === 'stage-no-date');

        if (restul.TOTAL_IND === -1) {
            restul.TOTAL_IND = arrayInd.findIndex(e => e === 'stage-is-red');

            if (restul.TOTAL_IND === -1) {
                restul.TOTAL_IND = arrayInd.findIndex(e => e === 'stage-is-yellow');

                if (restul.TOTAL_IND === -1) {
                    restul.TOTAL_IND = arrayInd.findIndex(e => e === 'stage-is-green');

                    if (restul.TOTAL_IND === -1) {
                        restul.TOTAL_TEXT = 'Done';
                        restul.TOTAL_IND = arrayInd.findIndex(e => e === 'stage-is-red-done');

                        if (restul.TOTAL_IND === -1) {
                            restul.TOTAL_IND = arrayInd.findIndex(e => e === 'stage-is-yellow-done');

                            if (restul.TOTAL_IND === -1) {
                                restul.TOTAL_IND = 'stage-is-green-done';
                            } else {
                                restul.TOTAL_IND = 'stage-is-yellow-done';
                            }
                        } else {
                            restul.TOTAL_IND = 'stage-is-red-done';
                        }
                    } else {
                        restul.TOTAL_IND = 'stage-is-green';
                        restul.TOTAL_TEXT = 'Deviation is ok';
                    }
                } else {
                    restul.TOTAL_IND = 'stage-is-yellow'
                    restul.TOTAL_TEXT = 'Deviation is normal';
                }
            } else {
                restul.TOTAL_IND = 'stage-is-red'
                restul.TOTAL_TEXT = 'Deviation is bad';
            }
        } else {
            restul.TOTAL_IND = 'stage-no-date'
            restul.TOTAL_TEXT = 'No deadlines';
        }
    }

    return restul;
}
```

I think this is bad code. Please share with me experience on how to do it right.

Comment: All your `if` have the same check `restul.TOTAL_IND === -1` - is it normal ?

Comment: @Weedoze it sort of is - each nested `if` then overwrites the value.

Comment: @VLAZ I understand but what's the goal of having 6 `if` if it will always get in the final `if` ?

Comment: have a dictionary with the states where every state has a numeric value. The lower the value, the worse for example. Loop over the passed states and find the the min in the dict?

Comment: @Weedoze it's essentially 6 `if`s that you're supposed to check and at some point give up and go into an `else`. Also...as you can guess - that's not the best way to write this.

Comment: so it doesn't matter whether to return whether the worst element is found on which stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to find the first matching entry that appears in an array, and create an object from it. One way to do this concisely would be to create an object, whose keys are the stage strings (eg `stage-is-empty`), whose values are the associated value for the `TOTAL_TEXT` property in the returned object. Then iterate over the entries of the object, and find the first one whose stage string appears in the array. From that entry, construct the object to return:

```
const textByStageStr = {
  'stage-is-empty': '',
  'stage-no-date': 'No deadlines',
  'stage-is-red': 'Deviation is bad',
  'stage-is-yellow': 'Deviation is normal',
  'stage-is-green': 'Deviation is ok',
  'stage-is-red-done': 'Done',
  'stage-is-yellow-done': 'Done',
  'stage-is-green-done': 'Done'
};
const setTotalIndForStage = (arrayInd) => {
  arrayInd = arrayInd.filter((item, i) => arrayInd.indexOf(item) === i);
  const entry = Object.entries(textByStageStr)
    .find(([stageStr]) => arrayInd.includes(stageStr));
  return {
    TOTAL_IND: entry[0],
    TOTAL_TEXT: entry[1]
  };
}
```

Because your final nested `else` has a `TOTAL_IND` of `'stage-is-green-done'` in case nothing is matched in the other conditions, I'm assuming that it will exist in the array in that case (and you're just not bothering to do a `findIndex` check because you've already exhausted all other possibilities).

Note that if you're only using `findIndex` so that you can compare the result against -1, it would be much easier to use `.includes` instead. Eg, in your original code, if you start with

```
restul.TOTAL_IND = arrayInd.findIndex(e => e === 'stage-no-date');
if (restul.TOTAL_IND === -1) {
```

if you don't use the result from the `findIndex` again, just use `.includes`:

```
if (!arrayInd.includes('stage-no-date')) {
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a lookup object with `Array.prototype.reduce()` as follows:

```js
const stages = {
  'stage-no-date': 0, 
  'stage-is-red': 1,
  'stage-is-yellow': 2,
  'stage-is-green': 3,
  'stage-is-red-done': 4,
  'stage-is-yellow-done': 5,
  'stage-is-green-done': 6
};

const findWorst = (array) => array.reduce(
  (a, v) => stages[v] < stages[a] ? v : a,
  'stage-is-green-done'
);

console.log(findWorst(['stage-is-empty', 'stage-is-green-done', 'stage-no-date']));
console.log(findWorst(['stage-is-done', 'stage-no-date', 'stage-is-yellow']));
console.log(findWorst(['stage-is-green', 'stage-is-red']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move all stages into an array with wanted result and perform a search.

```
const
    stages = [
        { TOTAL_IND: 'stage-is-empty', TOTAL_TEXT: '' },
        { TOTAL_IND: 'stage-no-date', TOTAL_TEXT: 'No deadlines' },
        { TOTAL_IND: 'stage-is-red', TOTAL_TEXT: 'Deviation is bad' },
        { TOTAL_IND: 'stage-is-yellow', TOTAL_TEXT: '' },
        { TOTAL_IND: 'stage-is-green', TOTAL_TEXT: '' },
        { TOTAL_IND: 'stage-is-red-done', TOTAL_TEXT: '' },
        { TOTAL_IND: 'stage-is-yellow-done', TOTAL_TEXT: '' },
    ],
    setTotalIndForStage = arrayInd =>
        stages.find(({ TOTAL_IND }) => arrayInd.some(v => TOTAL_IND === v)) ||
        stages[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply start with an ordered array of the states, from worse to best :

`const orderedStates = ["stage-no-date", "stage-is-red", "stage-is-yellow", "stage-is-green-done"];`

Then, for each value, check if your array contains it. If it does, stop searching and return it. It will automatically be the worse state. Here's the full code :

```js
const orderedStates = ["stage-no-date", "stage-is-red", "stage-is-yellow", "stage-is-green-done"];


const setTotalIndForStage = (arrayInd) => {
  for (let state of orderedStates) { // Starts with the worse, then increments to the best
    if (arrayInd.includes(state)) return state;
  }
  return "No state to return";
}

console.log(setTotalIndForStage(["stage-is-empty", "stage-is-green-done", "stage-no-date"]))
console.log(setTotalIndForStage(["stage-is-done", "stage-no-date", "stage-is-yellow"]))
console.log(setTotalIndForStage(["stage-is-green", "stage-is-red"]))
```

It can even be condensed to a one-liner, if you don't need a fallback value ( = if you're certain that the input array will always contain something to return) :

```js
const orderedStates = ["stage-no-date", "stage-is-red", "stage-is-yellow", "stage-is-green-done"];

const setTotalIndForStage = arrayInd => { for (let state of orderedStates) if(arrayInd.includes(state)) return state; }

console.log(setTotalIndForStage(["stage-is-empty", "stage-is-green-done", "stage-no-date"]))
console.log(setTotalIndForStage(["stage-is-done", "stage-no-date", "stage-is-yellow"]))
console.log(setTotalIndForStage(["stage-is-green", "stage-is-red"]))
```